# How to add an icon to an iText PdfPCell

Tags: itext, glyphicons

I am trying to create a `PdfPTable` with an icon in one cell (glyphicon-lock) and text in the other. Can this be done?

The issue is that the icon is a font icon (part of bootstrap glyphicons), so it isn't an actual image file. Will I have to embed the glyphicon font files and use the hex code for the "image" I want? Is there another way?

```
Phrase phrase = new Phrase(text, font);
cell = new PdfPCell( phrase );
cell.setColspan(this.colSpan);
cell.setBorder(border);
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(horizontalAlign);
cell.setVerticalAlignment(verticalAlign);
```

This is code for one cell. I have another that creates a new `Phrase` with an `Image`.

Comment: You would do it the same way in the PDF as you would do on the web: reference the font and use the character that corresponds to the glyph that you want to us. On the web you often use CSS and `content` for the glyph but what really matters is the character, you could do this in HTML just as easy. So just embed the font (which you need to have a license to do to) and use the character code that corresponds to the glyph. There's really no difference between Helvetica capital `A` ASCII 65 and glyphicon smiley face Unicode PUA e600. A font is a font and a character is a character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if what the question is because you can create a 2 column table.

```
PdfPTable mainTable = new PdfpTable(2);
mainTable.addCell(<phrase cell>);
mainTable.addCell(<image cell>);
```

You can also, if that was the question, add a nested table to a single cell in your main table. Something like this (to illustrate):

```
Phrase phrase = new Phrase(text, font);
cell1 = new PdfPCell( phrase );

Image img = ...
cell2 = new PdfPCell( img );

//Create nested table
PdfPTable dummyTable = new PdfPTable(2);
dummyTable.addCell(cell1);
dummyTable.addCell(cell2);

//Add nestedTable to cell of your main table
PdfPCell myCell = new PdfPCell(dummyTable)
mainTable.addCell(myCell)
```

Comment: Correct, I've made a small code sample: http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/IconDescriptionTable with this as result: http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/icon_description.pdf

Comment: In my sample, the icon is scaled to fit the cell. If you want to see the different options, please take a look at the example from chapter 4 of my book that demonstrates different ways to add an image to a cell: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=84 (you can avoid scaling, you can add the image in *composite mode*, etc...) As @Perneel explains: your question isn't entirely clear. Maybe you should read the documentation.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of clarity. What I cant figure out is how to use a glyphicon which is a font icon in a table. There isnt an image file but a css class name that refers to a hex code.

http://marcoceppi.github.io/bootstrap-glyphicons/